# Post to feed in dekstop application shows error + captcha after posting some URLs

Tags: facebook-graph-api, captcha, block, feed, facebook-chat

I'm using the 'feed dialog' with my Facebook desktop appliaction to recommend my app (and not using prefilled text).

This dialog worked well before, but since Sunday after trying to post I'm redirected to an error page which requests captcha filling, and once it's done I receive an error page.

At the beginning I replaced the URI, which worked and I was able to post normally, but since yesterday Replacing the URI or the URL doesn't work anymore.

Do you have any idea what can cause this?

Comment: You might be better off asking this on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/). It isn't really a programming question. Flagging to migrate.

Comment: I think this may be a programming question. @Ofri Stern - can you edit to clarify either way? Is this desktop app something you wrote?

Comment: @Tim Post, yes - this is a desktop app. The 'post to feed' still doesn't work when using any of our domains (these aren't blocked) - we're always redirected to an error page with captcha. 
When using a different URI (like google) it works well. 
Do you have any idea what can cause this/solve this?

Answer (score 1):

even i have been getting the same problem. the feed dialog directs me to a captcha and even if i enter the correct words it gives me an error that the words did not match. i was using the feed dialog to publish on my wall through an app. the legacy rest api is however working flawlessly.

Comment: do you have any idea what's the cause of this? let's update this thread if we get new info :)